# Excel indirect reference produces a #ref error

Tags: excel, vba, ref

I am trying to dynamically reference a cell on a different open and visible worksheet on the same workbook by using the INDIRECT function. When I make the cell reference with a static value, it works fine, but does not if the reference is not static. With the code snippet below, $A$31 is the sheet name, F9 is the cell reference for that sheet. This works fine. However, it is the F9 than needs to be dynamic, such as G9, H9 and F10, F11.

```
=INDIRECT("'" & $A$31 & "'!F9")
```

I would have thought the following snippet should have been the change to make. However this only results in a #REF error

```
=INDIRECT("'" & $A$31 & "'!" & F9)
```

What changes do I need to make, and why am I getting the error?

Comment: first write the same formula inside indirect to another cell and see if you get a valid address or not.  like `="'" & $A$31 & "'!" & F9`

Comment: Removing the INDIRECT I end up with a concatenated string of the sheet name from $A$31 and whatever value is in F9 on the current Activesheet

Comment: `=INDIRECT("'" & $A$31 & "'!" & F9)` this should work. Check & double check your sheet name and referenced cell.

Comment: Your last attempt works fine for me. I get a #REF error if the sheet in A31 doesn't exist. However, consider using INDIRECT(ADDRESS)).

Comment: As I said, the first version works fine. But isolating the F9 like in the second does not. The sheet reference name clearly works. These are the variations I've tried in their own cell at the same time, with the literal results afterward

1) =INDIRECT("'" & $A$31 & "'!F9")  = 2,works fine

2) =INDIRECT("'" & $A$31 & "'!" & F9) = #REF!

3) =CONCATENATE("'", $A$31, "'!",F9) = 'Sheet1'!y, not fine (y is in that cell)

4) =INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'" & $A$31 & "'!",F9)) = #REF!

5) ="'" & $A$31 & "'!F9" = 'Sheet1'!F9

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I'm sure how the code works but will work it out later. The dynamic cell reference part needs to be reworded from: & F9 to: & CELL("address", F9). "address' seems to be a key phrase

```
=INDIRECT("'" & $A$31 & "'!" & CELL("address",F9))
```